# How to access variables from a closed Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Suppose I have a function in my html file like

```
<script>
        ;(function(){
            function execute(output) {
                 return output;
            }
        })();
</script>
```

and then another one

```
<script>
        ;(function(){
            console.log(execute('test'));
        })();
</script>
```

Now I get `ReferenceError: execute is not defined`

How can I access that `execute` function if it's contained in another closed function?

Comment: The point of the first snippet is to prevent `execute` from existing outside its scope. You need to somehow return the function if you want it to be available,

Comment: Maybe you can try adding the second `IIFE` inside the first one. Or just add the logic inside the second method inside the first `IIFE`. Or define `execute` with global scope.

Comment: The trivial answer is to move `execute` outside of that IIFE. Are we talking about a 3rd party script here? Or is this your own design?

Answer (score 1):

To access a variable (or function) defined beforehand, the variable (or function) must be in scope. The simplest way would be to global scope `execute`. This is arguably bad practice (and seems useless by trivializing your closed function), but without further context to your situation, we can't suggest more accurate solutions:

```
<script>
        ;(function(){
            window.execute = output => {
                 return output;
            }
        })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**why is this happening**

Javascript has function scope. This means that alle de variables and function that are declared inside a function are only accessible inside that function

**how to fix this**

If you are using a bundler then I would recommend you to look in to ES6 Modules.

If not, the easy but dirty way to fix this is to assign it to a global object ( `window` in the browser and `global` in node )

**example**

```
function myGlobalFunction() { alert('it works') }
window.myGlobalFunction = myGlobalFunction
```

Just make sure they are loaded in the correct order

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript has [function scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/), if you have declared a function or variable within a function, it can only be accessed/referenced within the scope of that parent function. However, you can return an object mapping of the child functions within the parent function like in the example snippet below. Not sure if that is more what you're looking for?

```js
let executeScope = (function() {

  function init() {
    // do some init work here..
  }

  function execute(input) {
    let output = input * 2;
    return output;
  }

  function test() {
    console.log('test');
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    execute: execute,
    test: test
  };
})();

executeScope.init();
console.log(executeScope.execute(2));
executeScope.test();
```

Comment: @Dmitry Paranyushkin did you ever get the results you were looking for on this?